# How to add 'lib' to LOAD_PATH using Gemfile without gemspec?

Tags: ruby, bundler, require

I started a small project with `bundle init`. Actually I build an app, not a gem, so I decided not to use **.gemspec** file.
And I faced with the problem that I can not use `require` to require files located in `lib`. For example, on `bundle exec ruby bin/console` I get:

> cannot load such file -- new/gem

With gemspec file it will work because it has `require_paths = ["lib"]` option by default and after `require "bundler/setup"` you can use `require` to access files located in `lib`.

If I do not use gemspec file, how can I hint Bundler that I would like to have possibility to `require` from `lib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways:

1. Use `require_relative "../lib/app"`
2. Add `lib` to `$LOAD_PATH` in `bin/console`: `$LOAD_PATH.unshift "./lib"`
3. Just add it inline on the command line: `bundle exec ruby -Ilib bin/console`

Note though that if you're using `require_relative` in your app (and you should be), then `lib` doesn't *need* to be in `$LOAD_PATH`, you should just be able to `require "path/to/app"` wherever you want to load it.

Comment: Thank you. The 2nd option fits most of all. Because `rubocop-packaging` says I should not use `require_relative` and manually specifying `-I` would be too tedious. I only thought that there will be some Bundler option which I am not aware about, but it actually gets solved with plain Ruby.

Comment: @Kirill Interesting. Just read that documentation and it does make sense, but to be clear, that's for _test_ code: "We want to emphasize that there is nothing wrong with using require_relative inside lib/, it’s just using it from your test code to the lib directory prevents the "test the library installed system-wide" use case."

For tests it's fairly common to just add `lib` to `$LOAD_PATH` in your test helper.

Comment: Thank you, Lee. Did not know this rule is for tests, because it gets triggered on a file in a root in my case. This makes sense for tests, RSpec adds `lib` and `spec` to `$LOAD_PATH` by default